# how to print domain name for route53 DNS

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-route53

I am new to python and learning, I am writing a code to print the domain name and type and value of a route53 hosted zone.
When it loops through CNAME, I get the value of CNAME and not its domain name.

```
def list(zoneid, region, profile):
  rrs = []
  aws_session = boto3.session.Session(region=region, profile=profile)
  route53 = aws_session.client('route53')
  paginator = route53.get_paginator('list_resource_record_sets')

  page = paginator.paginate(
  HostedZoneId=zoneid,
  PaginationConfig={
      'MaxItems': 500,
      'PageSize': 500
  }
  )



  for i in page:
    for record in i['ResourceRecordSets']:
      if record['Type'] == 'CNAME':
        a.extend(x['Value'] for x in record['ResourceRecords'])
      elif record['Type'] == 'A':
        a.append(record['Name'])

  return a
```

print record[Name] - gives the domain name. But how can I include it in  "a.extend(x['Value'] for x in record['ResourceRecords'])" this line

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Value` key available for any of the resource record as can be seen from the sample response [on the docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Paginator.ListResourceRecordSets):

```
{
    'ResourceRecordSets': [
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'Type': 'SOA'|'A'|'TXT'|'NS'|'CNAME'|'MX'|'NAPTR'|'PTR'|'SRV'|'SPF'|'AAAA'|'CAA',
            'SetIdentifier': 'string',
            'Weight': 123,
            'Region': 'us-east-1'|'us-east-2'|'us-west-1'|'us-west-2'|'ca-central-1'|'eu-west-1'|'eu-west-2'|'eu-west-3'|'eu-central-1'|'ap-southeast-1'|'ap-southeast-2'|'ap-northeast-1'|'ap-northeast-2'|'sa-east-1'|'cn-north-1'|'cn-northwest-1'|'ap-south-1',
            'GeoLocation': {
                'ContinentCode': 'string',
                'CountryCode': 'string',
                'SubdivisionCode': 'string'
            },
            'Failover': 'PRIMARY'|'SECONDARY',
            'MultiValueAnswer': True|False,
            'TTL': 123,
            'ResourceRecords': [
                {
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'AliasTarget': {
                'HostedZoneId': 'string',
                'DNSName': 'string',
                'EvaluateTargetHealth': True|False
            },
            'HealthCheckId': 'string',
            'TrafficPolicyInstanceId': 'string'
        },
    ],
    'IsTruncated': True|False,
    'MaxItems': 'string',
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

I think you just want to refer to the `Name` key:

> #### Name (string) --
>
> The name of the domain you want to perform the action on.
>
> Enter a fully qualified domain name, for example, `www.example.com`.
>   You can optionally include a trailing dot. If you omit the trailing
>   dot, Amazon Route 53 still assumes that the domain name that you
>   specify is fully qualified. This means that Amazon Route 53 treats
>   `www.example.com` (without a trailing dot) and `www.example.com`.
>   (with a trailing dot) as identical.